Excel VBA code for hiding/showing rows when one specific cell is value either 0 or above 0
I can't seem to make this work. It is supposed to unlock the sheet, change the row status and lock back with the same PW.
Any ideas what might be wrong? I'm very new to VBA and this code is made using AI.
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = "$M$10" Then
       If Target.Value > 0 Then
           If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
               ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="TL1234"
               Rows("18:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
               ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="TL1234"
           End If
       Else
           If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
               ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="TL1234"
               Rows("18:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
               ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="TL1234"
           End If
       End If
   End If
End Sub

Rows image
I've tried with and without the "Activesheet"-lines to make it simpler, couldn't quite make that work either, even though it worked previously...

Could you share the formula in M10?

Your code works well for me in perfect conditions. However, if the sheet is currently not protected for whatever reason (debugging for instance), the code won't appear to do much at all.
Try this, it's tidier, will apply protection regardless of current state - and should therefore do what you need:
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const pwd As String = "TL1234"
    With Target
        If .Address = "$M$10" Then
             If .Parent.ProtectContents Then
                 .Parent.Unprotect Password:=pwd
             End If
             Rows("18:20").EntireRow.Hidden = (.Value > 0)
             .Parent.Protect Password:=pwd
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Hi, thank you for answering.
I've tried your coding but there might just be some other issue going on..
Same as the other guy answering:
I'm quite new to VBA so i'll try to retrace my steps for you..
I've made the sheet, saved it as excel file with active macros.
I'm opening VBA, inserting module and copy-paste your code into it and press save.
From here i just change values in excel and can see it doesn't work for me...
What am i doing wrong?

Make sure the code is pasted into the Sheet object, not a new module.

So one reason it may not be working is your double logic may be causing it to skip the procedure. For example, if the target value is greater than 0, but your worksheet isn't password protected it just ends right there.
This should be in the Sheet's code as well:

This macro will hide the row if the value is that and if it's not protected it won't protect it, but it won't skip the macro because it's not protected. I didn't want to add logic that says if it's not protected then protect it, as that would be problematic as it would constantly be locking the worksheet anytime anything changes.
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = "$M$10" Then
   If Target.Value > 0 Then
            If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
               ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="TL1234"
               Rows("18:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
               ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="TL1234"
            Else
                Rows("18:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
       Else
            If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
               ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="TL1234"
               Rows("18:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
               ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="TL1234"
            Else
                Rows("18:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
           End If
       End If
   End If
End Sub


Hi, thank you for answering.
I've tried your coding but there might just be some other issue going on..
I'm quite new to VBA so i'll try to retrace my steps for you..
I've made the sheet, saved it as excel file with active macros.
I'm opening VBA, inserting module and copy-paste your code into it and press save.
From here i just change values in excel and can see it doesn't work for me...
What am i doing wrong?

@jonathanJonfanbrandstrup added another detail that may have been overlooked. I hope this resolves your issue.

@jonathanJonfanbrandstrup see my screenshot where you're not inserting a MODULE you want to put the macro into the worksheet you see i have selected in the image.

I've made it work, and added another feature to which i hope you can help.. It is in another question..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78865728/password-protecting-sheet-vba-where-to-add
Hope you can help with the whole protect / unprotect issue once more :)

Did this answer resolve the question you posed in this post?

Check the cell format of $M$10 and make sure that it's not "Text".  If it's "Text", then the check for "$M&10>0" will always return false.  You can change the Cell Format to any of the Formats which return a numeric value or use "Val(Range("$M$10").Value)" in your code to force it to a numeric value.

OP isn't checking if the value < 0
