Password protecting Sheet VBA where to add
In the first part of the code, the "If Activesheet..." unlocks and locks again after use. I can't seem to hit the sweetspot when trying to incorporate it again in the 2nd half of my code.
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = "$M$10" Then
   If Target.Value > 0 Then
            If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
               ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
               Rows("18:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
               ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
            Else
                Rows("18:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
       Else
            If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
               ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
               Rows("18:19").EntireRow.Hidden = True
               ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
            Else
                Rows("18:19").EntireRow.Hidden = True
           End If
       End If
   End If
    



'/// 2nd half
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    Dim tcell As Range: Set tcell = ws.Range("M3")
    If Intersect(tcell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim tString As String: tString = CStr(tcell.Value)
    
   If InStr(1, tString, "Halv" & ChrW(229) & "r ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        With ws.Range("C41:E54")
            '.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' white background
            .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' white font
            .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            .Interior.TintAndShade = 0
            .Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
            
        End With
    Call Makro4
    
    ElseIf InStr(1, tString, "Kvartal ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' is equal
        With ws.Range("C42:C46,C50:C54,E42:E46,E50:E54")
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow background
            .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'black font
        End With
        With ws.Range("C47:E47")
            .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
    Call Makro5
    
    Else
        
    End If
   
  
   
End Sub

I've tried to replicate the top code with the Else and repeat of command

I think it would be good to explain what exactly you want your code TO DO. Your code as it is works only if the changed cell is "$M$10". Now, what ELSE would you like to happen? To make the code working for a change in "M3", too? Or what? Anyhow,  Target.Worksheet will rase an error. Target.Parent will return the sheet, but this is useless in a Worksheet_Change event which is triggered by a change in the active sheet. Please, help us helping you by making us understand what you try doing...

In the 2nd half of code (when unlocked at least), the code changes some cell formatting based on a string in cell M3. I want for the Unlocking/Locking mechanism to be applied to the 2nd half of the code, the way is works in the 1st half.
Makes sense, or am i just mumbling?

Not really, too much... Can you try answering my question: Would you like to make the event being triggered for a change in M3, too? And whatever is in your code... I mean, to be triggered (to work) for both cells addresses...

I'm here from your other question but unsure what you're trying to accomplish with the sheet protections? Check if it's there, if it is, unprotect, do the macro, then re-protect and if not just go with the procedure as usual?

Here's a basic version of the second half of your code:
'/// 2nd half
    
If Target.Address <> "$M$3" Then Exit Sub

Dim tString As String: tString = CStr(Target.Value)

If InStr(1, tString, "Halv" & ChrW(229) & "r ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

    If Me.ProtectContents Then
        Me.Unprotect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
    End If

    With Me.Range("C41:E54")
        '.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' white background
        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' white font
        .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        .Interior.TintAndShade = 0
        .Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Call Makro4

    Me.Protect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"

ElseIf InStr(1, tString, "Kvartal ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' is equal

    If Me.ProtectContents Then
        Me.Unprotect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
    End If

    With Me.Range("C42:C46,C50:C54,E42:E46,E50:E54")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow background
        .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'black font
    End With

    With Me.Range("C47:E47")
        .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End With

    Call Makro5

    Me.Protect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"

End If

For the second half, you seem to have taken a different approach to checking the Target cell.  Using the Intersect method tends to be more useful when you're checking if the Target cell is within a larger range.  If you're checking for a single cell you may as well use the Address property as you did in the first half.
You've also changed from using ActiveSheet in favour of a worksheet variable called ws.  There's nothing wrong with this but when you're writing code in a worksheet module you can reference the worksheet which contains the code with the built-in Me keyword.
As a basic rule of thumb: unprotect the sheet just before you make changes to it and re-protect it after you've finished making changes! It looks like your code in the first half does this successfully but I'm not sure that you've quite hit the sweet spot there yet.  After you've established that the Target cell is M10, you're going to make a change to the worksheet whether M10's value is greater than 0 or not.  You can unprotect the sheet once and re-protect it once:
If Target.Address = "$M$10" Then

    'after this, you're going to make changes in any case,
    'so unprotect the sheet once here
    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
    End If

    If Target.Value > 0 Then
        Rows("18:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("18:19").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    're-protect the sheet once after making your changes
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"

End If

You could make it even shorter by eliminating the inner If statement and replacing it with a single line which incorporates a Boolean expression:
If Target.Address = "$M$10" Then

    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
    End If

    Rows("18:19").EntireRow.Hidden = Not (Target.Value > 0)

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"

End If


Please, try the next adapted code:

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.address = "$M$10" Then
    If Target.Value > 0 Then
             If Me.ProtectContents Then
                Me.Unprotect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
                rows("18:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Me.Protect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
             Else
                 rows("18:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
             End If
    Else
             If Me.ProtectContents Then
                Me.Unprotect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
                rows("18:19").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Me.Protect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet"
             Else
                 rows("18:19").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
    End If
ElseIf Target.address = "$M$3" Then
    Dim tString As String: tString = CStr(Target.Value)
    
      If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
        Dim boolProt As Boolean
        If Me.ProtectContents Then Me.Unprotect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet": boolProt = True 'unprotect it if the case
      End If
        If InStr(1, tString, "Halv" & ChrW(229) & "r ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            With Me.Range("C41:E54")
                .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' white font
                .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                .Interior.TintAndShade = 0
                .Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
            'Call Makro4 'to test, this macro is necessasry
        
        ElseIf InStr(1, tString, "Kvartal ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' is equal
            With Me.Range("C42:C46,C50:C54,E42:E46,E50:E54")
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow background
                .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'black font
            End With
            With Me.Range("C47:E47")
                .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End With
            'Call Makro5 'to test, this macro is necessasry
        
        Else
            'do whatever
            Debug.Print "Something else...": Stop
        End If
    If boolProt Then Me.Protect Password:="TL1234Kvalitet":
 End If
End Sub

